# How to validate form array with dynamic values using form builder

Tags: angular, angular9, formbuilder, formgroups

Am working on angular project where I need to submit a form with some values where the exams

form fields are dynamically created when I click the add button each row() will be added in the form.

for adding each exam values. I could delete each row as well in the form.

The requirement is I need to display a validation message for subject, mark and exams for each dynamic row created on click submit button if it is invalid/not selected. The exams field is a multiple checkbox list validate if nothing is selected

```
<form [formGroup] = "SettingsForm" (ngSubmit) = "SettingsFormSubmit()">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-4">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" formControlName="Name">
      </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-4 ">
        <p *ngIf="submitted && SettingsForm.get('Name').invalid class="text-danger">
          Name is required.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-12">
        <table class="table" formArrayName="PersonalData">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Subject</th>
              <th>Mark</th>
              <th>Exams</th>
              <th>Delete</th>
              <th><button type="button"  (click)="addPersonalData()" class="btn-blank">Add</button></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr [hidden]="!data.value.active"   *ngFor="let data of PersonalData().controls;let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
              <td>
                <select class="form-control" formControlName="subject"  >
                  <option>Select Subject</option>
                  <ng-container *ngFor="let subject of subjects">
                  <option  value="{{ subject.id }}" >{{ subject.subject_name }}</option>
                  </ng-container>
                </select>
                <ng-container *ngIf="data.get(subject).invalid">
                  <span class="">error message</span>
                </ng-container>
              </td>
              <td>
                <select class="form-control" formControlName="mark">   
                  <option>Select Mark</option>
                  <option>50</option>
                  <option>60</option>
                  <option>90</option>
                </select>
                <ng-container *ngIf="data.get(mark).invalid">
                  <span class="">error message</span>
                </ng-container>
              </td>
              <td>
                <mat-form-field>
                  <mat-label>Select Exams</mat-label>
                  <mat-select  #examsSelect multiple formControlName="exams" >
                    <mat-option (click)="examsSelect()" *ngFor="let term of terms" [value]="term.id">
                      {{term.name}}
                    </mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
                  <ng-container *ngIf="data.get(exams).invalid">
                  <span class="">error message</span>
                </ng-container>
              </td>
              <td><button type="button"  (click)="deletedata(i)" >Delete</button>
              </td>
              <td><button type="button"  (click)="addPersonalData()" >Add</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </div>
   </form> 



   this.SettingsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    id: [''], 
    Name: ['',Validators.required],
    PersonalData: this.formBuilder.array([this.formBuilder.control('', Validators.required)])
   });


  PersonalData() : FormArray {
    return this.SettingsForm.get("PersonalData") as FormArray
  }

  newPersonalData(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      id: '',
      subject: '',
      mark: '',
     exams: '',
   })
  }

  addPersonalData() {
    this.PersonalData().push(this.newPersonalData());
  }
```

Iam saving each PersonalData to the formbuilder dynamically so at a time suppose if I have added 3 rows added then a group of 3 form fields will be their as formarray with same formcontrolname how to validate and show error messages for all the dynamically generated form fields? I got error when I do so..

```
`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'invalid')`
```

Comment: You are adding form control `this.formBuilder.array([this.formBuilder.control` at initial stage. But afterwards you are pushing formgroup inside array?

Comment: When you iterate array your first control is formcontrol not formgroup so at that point he is not going to get any subject or mark, so the null error

Comment: oh! i just added that later for validating added values, initially it was this.formBuilder.array([])!

Comment: so i this fine if i  declare like this this.formBuilder.array([]), i could save the the dynamic values submitted when i use this.formBuilder.array([])! but validation is the issue!

Comment: Does null issue went of? If share code on stackblitz I can make it work.

Comment: No it is still there!

Comment: This ` data.get(subject).invalid` should be `data.get('subject').invalid`.. inverted comma missing ..same for others

Comment: sorry it is a typo, am using codes with only. Cannot find control with path: 'personalData-> 0 -> subject' is the error am facing.I think i need to  submit each dynamic row with different formcontrol names right?like subject{{i}}?

Comment: for reference check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ttjfe2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Does it work now? Its running reference with validation

Comment: yeah it is working , it is just because of the validation need to be added  for each dynamic form fields!Thank you so much for the help! @navnath

Comment: On more issue is there...the default value of select field eg: "select mark" is not selected by default, i tried some solutions we normally do but not working because of dynamic field.

Comment: We can do it. Just add `<option value="">Select Mark</option>` and `mark: ['', Validators.required],`  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ttjfe2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: oh yes! i just thought of the same but haven't tried it don't know why :) tried a lot of other complicated  methods! Thank you again!

Comment: may i ask one more small issue not regarding the technical stuff just encountered recently it is ok if this issue is out of scope from current scenario, as i have mentioned am using material design for one of the form field in my dynamic form when i show the error message  the message showing below material field is not aligned with others so need to apply my styles i have added styles but not working because of dynamic field. How to add styles for the <mat-form-field> in order to show the  error message properly aligned with other fields ?

Comment: i need to apply styles for the material form field as a dynamic padding is adding to the field when i click add button. i  need to change it! the styles are working when i inspect and check but not in live!

Comment: share it on stackblitz

Comment: @navnath the style is not properly displaying but the issue with error message is visible hope this will be fine to reveal the issue, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xppdd2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html I think you need to click the exam1 and exam2 values displayed there to see the error message design breaking!

Comment: Check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uvwzuc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html and let me know what exactly is the problem?

Comment: now the three text fields are material design the issue will no be there now.. when we add a normal select box as we did before along with material select box the message displayed below material design will be little  more below compared to others check now https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ve1dhc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html need to display error message just below the select box as we see for the first select box. yeah knowing that still i can make all the three select box material will work..!

Comment: You wan to use normal select along with mat-select?

Comment: yes, but its ok if it is time consuming and complicated i can use mat for all select! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form initialized as

```
this.SettingsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  id: [null],
  Name: [null, Validators.required],
  PersonalData: this.formBuilder.array([]),
});
```

Add validation for each dynamic field as

```
  newPersonalData(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      id: '',
      subject: [null, Validators.required],
      mark: [null, Validators.required],
      exams: [null, Validators.required],
    });
  }
```

There no field with name `active` so commented it

```
// [hidden]="!data.value.active"
<tr
*ngFor="let data of PersonalData().controls; let i = index"
[formGroupName]="i"
>
```

To do validation encode control name in inverted comma

```
<ng-container *ngIf="data.get('subject').invalid">
```

[Sample Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ttjfe2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Thanks for sharing, let me try this , but i was already doing this <ng-container *ngIf="data.get('subject').invalid"> before getting the error i have mentioned. But may be it is because of some other reason i guess it might be because of the the validators needed for each fields in formgroup!

Comment: Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted and upvote, if it solved your issue

Comment: yeah sure,  could you please  get any reference of applying CSS for dynamically added mat field in my scenario? Thanks!

Comment: It's not the problem with mat-select. I would say you should either use mat-select or normal select for all dropdowns.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your `formControlName.errors` to check if there is an error in it directly in your html like so `*ngIf="name.errors?.required"` (for a Validators.required case). You can then display a message like: "This value is required".

It can also be called in the `component.ts` to validate forms before sending data.

Enjoy coding!

Comment: Thanks for helping out, am saving each PersonalData to the formbuilder dynamically so at a time suppose i have added 3 rows then a group of 3 for fields will be their as formarray with same formcontrolname how to validate and show error messages for all the dynamically generated form fields? i got error when i do so.. ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'invalid')

Comment: You need to create separate components for your lines, this way you will isolate  the forms from each other and the validations will be easier to perform and replicate.

Comment: Yeah , thanks for the suggestion but looking forward to validate the fields in same form!

Comment: Change your formControlName maybe? so they do not have the same name?